# Why voltage is shifted in my schematic?

Tags: simulation, spice, kicad, common-emitter, ngspice

I'm learning basics of electronics and trying to get familiar with the common emitter topology. This is my schematic diagram:

[image: Schematic diagram]

When I try to simulate it in Kicad I get this:

[image: Simulation]

Everything works as I expect except the fact that "base" is 0.4V higher than "in". How this can be explained?

*UPD.* It looks like the voltage shift is not constant. If I change the capacitor and the resistor this way:

[image: Schematic diagram 2]

Thrn the voltages become equal soon:
[image: Simulation 2]

It leaves me with question why these voltages differ by 0.4V initially? Is it something specific to ngspice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a fixed DC reference for the base, so the simulator is picking some number thats resulting from the internal transistor model. Try putting a 1 meg resistor on the base to ground, bet that mystery voltage disappears

Google 'bias BJT base' and you'll find the knowledge you seek   :)

Comment: even better if 1M pulls up

Answer (score 2):

Capacitor C1 breaks any DC connection between `in` and `base`.

You could add a 100 V (or -100 V) DC source in series with V2, and you’d get the same result for the voltage at `base`, at least after any start up transients die off.

Comment: But it doesn't explain 0.4V shift in my simulation.

Comment: You don't have a fixed DC reference for the base, so the simulator is picking some number thats resulting from the internal transistor model.   Try putting a 1 meg resistor on the base to ground, bet that mystery voltage disappears

Comment: @KyleB thank you! It pretty precisely answers my question. It would mark it accepted if it wasn't a comment.

Comment: Ok   I made it an answer   ;)

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I was surprised to see a waveform at transistor collector...it *should* end up very near Vcc of 3.3V, with only a little squiggle of 10kHz.

Transistor base-emitter junction acts as a diode clamp, which only accepts current at the most positive peak of the AC waveform. This peak current biases the capacitor to a more negative average voltage after some long time.

An LTSpice transient simulation ran for 100 seconds, plotting from 99.999s to 100s (below). After this long time, collector waveform turns into a very short spike. Note that average base voltage  (green) has fallen to nearly -0.5V...the base only conducts current for a brief moment at the +ve peak:[image: collector and base voltage transient plot]
[image: schematic]

Comment: Indeed, I can reproduce it on 100 sec interval too. Would a resistor between base and ground solve it? If so, how could I calculate its value?

Comment: Note I only suggested that base resistor earlier to demonstrate what happens when you fix the DC bias to something (in that case "gnd").     Your actual goal is to set a known DC bias at the base.  You need to to that to get the transistor to conduct.   The easiest, maybe most common, way is by a voltage divider between VCC and GND.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNp-WxkF5h4

Comment: Yes, @KyleB suggestion of a base-to-ground resistor can work. A DC voltage divider that biases base up closer to +0.6V is the better idea, especially if input voltage is a small amplitude. If you want to ensure that collector remains at Vcc when no signal (or small signal) is present, a diode clamp from base-to-ground is OK...with cathode connected to base.

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfect to make a sine to square limiter with a single transistor for variable input amplitudes.

For larger input when Vbe conducts more at 0.6V with lower impedance it clips and changes the DC bias offset.

### New and Improved

But the best way is to use a pullup to Vcc,

- **Rb+/ Rc = 10**  for pullup Rb+   (R+/R4)
- **Rc / Rs = 10** for serial input Rs  (R4/R1)
- then Rb+/Rs=100 with not much attenuation, yet better DC bias to base current.
- V gain = Rc/rE until saturated the reduces a lot (towards 10% hFE) rE is base-emitter resistance

Once you learn these kind of impedance ratios, design gets easier.

[image]

Don't make the input cap RC=T too big otherwise the startup time can be too long.

[Falstad SIM Tool](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCsICMA2SAORB2ALI3y5E1s4SRkJEE4BmAKAHcQAmbCbNEGm5ED8OgCcWbPp1YRmYTpViwhXHi1aLezOL0p0ALiMnTVLA5SjZc8NMzQVM0zDMiEwcOGjAFkiGjmzMkcMEYkAE4-KXFRcIEAc0N1Xm41TD9AgCU9MSQzTIh2CBpIGnBisEcFRMyKxFDixDlA4RR9Tmqw4yQ5OgBjJAojFsQ2mRZITABTAFpMUzwNbBpmYK9Fqkw6dMRB-vJsbZM3KFn645gUkrKAeUNWrmIQs8C2IqblXatxNGHsAH1kH7BvoNSMhvqVCMEwMwrMwsDQ2DhgqDoDBEN9mGjvj96AB7Do7YpsYIOZDqKByYKYDykyR4nFIRD49i0PBcSCLXw4axuGGsClklFIJB0GgtXJkhAMgCyAEMAB4AHQAzgA1bEAG200uiYzoQA)